# Is it possible to use a Partial Credit Model estimated using eRm to predict person abilities in an extended dataset?

Tags: r

I am using the eRm package in R to examine the properties of a clinical rating scale using a Partial Credit Model (PCM). I understand how to extract the person ability estimations (thetas) from a simple fitted PCM but I have a dataset with repeated observations (~1200 observations of the instrument in ~250 individuals). So as not to violate assumptions of conditional independence I've fitted the PCM to single observations drawn at random from each subject. This all works but I would now like to use the fitted PCM to generate person-ability estimates for the remaining ~950 observations *not* used to fit the model; and I can't see from the eRm package documentation how to do this?

Advice very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For reference should others be asking the same question, Patrick Nair (the package maintainer for eRm) confirms this is not possible in eRm at the time of writing but pointed me to the [PP package] as an interim solution[1](https://cran.r-project.org/package=PP)